# Possible to limit Google sheets API to only provided URLS?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a Chrome extension that access sheets that the user provides via URL, and at no point do I need to access anything other than specific ones that they provide. When they auth to give consent to this, it says that they are allowing my extension full access to ALL documents, which has had a few users contact me about asking why I need that access.

Most don't read this or care, but some do, and I'm wondering if there is some scope that I'm missing that I can use that will reduce my access to ease the mind of users, as I do not need to see or access anything other than specific urls that they provide.

Thanks